# How to calculate the mode of an array in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have an array defined as the following:

```
julia> a = [5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 12, 17, 67, 68, 69, 72, 74, 74, 92, 93, 100, 105, 110, 120, 124]
21-element Vector{Int64}:
   5
   6
   7
   8
  10
  12
  12
  17
  67
  68
   ⋮
  74
  74
  92
  93
 100
 105
 110
 120
 124
```

I am able to calculate the standard deviation but there does not seem to be a mode function built into Julia like there is with the `std()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no built in function to do this, the `mode` function does exist in the [StatsBase package](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/v0.20/scalarstats.html#StatsBase.mode):

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> mode(a)
12
```